# Unity3D+iOS Dev, I wait for so long time to get the IAP SKProductsResponse

Tags: objective-c, ios, storekit, in-app-purchase

In the IAP dev,
first, I followed the instruction in the link:
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Luckily and quickly, I got the IAP dialog box poping up (Buy XXX for $0.99?). Everything seemed working! I then started to deal with the receipt validation stuff.

After one day or two, I got the ***Invalid Product ID*** thing. I added breakpoints almost everywhere and finally, I found the

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

method was not called at all. It then costed me about 2 weeks googling everything and I got no progress. Then I removed my startPayment method,

```
- (void)startPayment
{
   SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct: myProduct];
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

and added a breakpoint in the line

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

All right, I found the method got called after waiting for 3-5 seconds, and there's no ***Invalid Product ID*** issue.

Therefore, I called my ***startPayment*** method inside of the ***productsRequest didReceiveResponse*** method. Yes, the ***Invalid Product ID*** issue disappeared, but I got another problem.

My app crashed (back to iPhone's main menu) after 2-3 sec waiting, and then the IAP dialog box poped up after 1-2 sec. It looks like the dialog box pops up directly on the main menu of iPhone. When I clicked my app's icon again, the dialog box disappeared and the app started loading from the beginning.

Is there anybody could tell me what on earth is going on? Thank you very much!

Comment: "I wait for so long time to get the IAP SKProductsResponse in Xcode" - you can, Xcode won't ever receive such a response. At most your iOS app will, that's why you shouldn't refer to iOS programming as "Xcode programming" nor tag your questions with "xcode" which have actually nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchases has a queue of requests. If your request isn't finished it will remain on the queue and when your app restart will try to continue with the request. It's the developer's responsibility to finish the request by calling the appropriate method.

Remember: Apple's sandbox service can be slow, the live server should be much quicker.

Just today I integrated In-App purchase into an app, I'll post the code beneath for eductional purposes. I've chosen to put all code into a Singleton. Might not be the best solution (maybe it is, maybe it's not), but for my purposes it works out fine. My store will deal with only 1 product for now, the code might be a bit impractical when selling more products, though I do try to keep it in mind.

**P.S:** please note the code below is a work in progress. It seems to work out fine for me though, so it might help you solve your issues.

**ProductStore.h**

```
@interface FSProductStore : NSObject

+ (FSProductStore *)defaultStore;

// AppDelegate should call this on app start (appDidFinishLoading) ...
- (void)registerObserver;

// handling product requests ...
- (void)startProductRequestWithIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier
                        completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))completionHandler;
- (void)cancelProductRequest;

@end
```

**FSProductStore.m**

```
#import "FSProductStore.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "NSData+Base64.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "FSTransaction.h"


@interface FSProductStore () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

- (void)startTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;
- (void)validateReceipt:(NSData *)receiptData withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))completionHandler;

- (void)purchaseSuccess:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (void)purchaseFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKProductsRequest *currentProductRequest;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(BOOL success, NSError *error);

@end


@implementation FSProductStore

+ (FSProductStore *)defaultStore
{
    static FSProductStore *store;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (!store)
        {
            store = [[FSProductStore alloc] init];
        }
    });

    return store;
}

- (void)registerObserver
{
    DLog(@"registering observer ...");

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
}

#pragma mark - Products request delegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    if (!response.products || response.products.count == 0)
    {
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:FSMyAppErrorDomain code:FSNoProductsAvailableError];
        [self purchaseFailedWithError:error];
    }
    else
    {
        SKProduct *product = response.products[0];
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];

        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
        {
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
        }
        else
        {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:FSMyAppErrorDomain code:FSInAppPurchaseDisabledError];
            [self purchaseFailedWithError:error];
        }
        DLog(@"%@", response.products);
    }
}

#pragma mark - Payment transaction observer

// Sent when the transaction array has changed (additions or state changes).  Client should check state of transactions and finish as appropriate.
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    DLog(@"%@", transactions);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        DLog(@"%@", transaction);

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: [self startTransaction:transaction];    break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:     [self failedTransaction:transaction];   break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:  [self completeTransaction:transaction]; break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:   [self restoreTransaction:transaction];  break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}

// Sent when an error is encountered while adding transactions from the user's purchase history back to the queue.
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    DLog(@"%@", error);

    [self purchaseFailedWithError:error];
}

// Sent when transactions are removed from the queue (via finishTransaction:).
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue removedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    DLog(@"%@", transactions);
}

// Sent when all transactions from the user's purchase history have successfully been added back to the queue.
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    DLog(@"%@", queue);
}

// Sent when the download state has changed.
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads
{
    DLog(@"%@", downloads);
}


#pragma mark - Public methods

- (void)startProductRequestWithIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier
                        completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:FS_PRODUCT_DISABLE_ADS] == NO)
    {
        DLog(@"ERROR: invalid product identifier!");

        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:FSMyAppErrorDomain code:FSInvalidProductIdentifier];

        if (completionHandler)
        {
            completionHandler(NO, error);
        }

        return;
    }


    // cancel any existing product request (if exists) ...

    [self cancelProductRequest];


    // start new  request ...

    self.completionHandler = completionHandler;

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:productIdentifier];
    self.currentProductRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    _currentProductRequest.delegate = self;
    [_currentProductRequest start];
}

- (void)cancelProductRequest
{
    if (_currentProductRequest)
    {
        DLog(@"cancelling existing request ...");

        [_currentProductRequest setDelegate:nil];
        [_currentProductRequest cancel];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)startTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    DLog(@"starting transaction: %@", transaction);
}

- (void)completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self validateReceipt:transaction.transactionReceipt withCompletionHandler:^ (BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success)
        {
            // Your application should implement these two methods.
            [self recordTransaction:transaction];
            [self purchaseSuccess:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
        }
        else
        {
            // deal with error ...
            [self purchaseFailedWithError:error];
        }

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    }];
}

- (void)failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
        [self purchaseFailedWithError:transaction.error];
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction:transaction];
    [self purchaseSuccess:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    DLog(@"recording transaction: %@", transaction);


    // TODO: store for audit trail - perhaps on remote server?

    FSTransaction *transactionToRecord = [FSTransaction transactionWithIdentifier:transaction.transactionIdentifier receipt:transaction.transactionReceipt];
    [transactionToRecord store];
}

- (void)purchaseSuccess:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    // TODO: make purchase available to user - perhaps call completion block?

    DLog(@"transaction success for product: %@", productIdentifier);

    self.currentProductRequest = nil;

    if (_completionHandler)
    {
        _completionHandler(YES, nil);
    }
}

- (void)purchaseFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    DLog(@"%@", error);

    self.currentProductRequest = nil;

    if (_completionHandler)
    {
        _completionHandler(NO, error);
    }
}

- (void)validateReceipt:(NSData *)receiptData withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    DLog(@"validating receipt with Apple ...");

    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"receipt-data\" : \"%@\"}", [receiptData base64EncodedString]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:FS_URL_APPLE_VERIFY_RECEIPT];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody   = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^ (NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        DLog(@"%@", JSON);

        NSNumber *number  = [JSON objectForKey:@"status"];
        BOOL      success = number && (number.integerValue == 0);
        NSError  *error   = success ? nil : [NSError errorWithDomain:FSMyAppErrorDomain code:FSInvalidProductReceipt];

        if (completionHandler)
        {
            completionHandler(success, error);
        }

    } failure:^ (NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        if (completionHandler)
        {
            completionHandler(NO, error);
        }

    }];
    [operation start];
}

@end
```

The nice thing about the design of the class is that it's sort of a black box for In-App Purchases. Using the class is rather easy, for example the following code is used to buy the "disable ads" product:

```
- (void)disableAds
{
    [self showLoadingIndicator:YES forView:self.tableView];

    [[FSProductStore defaultStore] startProductRequestWithIdentifier:FS_PRODUCT_DISABLE_ADS completionHandler:^ (BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        [self showLoadingIndicator:NO forView:self.tableView];

        DLog(@"%d %@", success, error);

        if (success)
        {
            NSNumber *object = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FSShouldDisableAdsNotification object:object];

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            if (indexPath)
            {
                [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [UIAlertView showAlertViewWithError:error delegate:self];
        }

    }];
}
```

**P.S.:** the following macro is used for the receipt validation URL. I have 3 schemes: Debug (development), Release (testing) & Distribution (AppStore):

```
// In-App purchase: we'll use the Sandbox environment for test versions ...

#if (DEBUG || RELEASE)
#define FS_URL_APPLE_VERIFY_RECEIPT [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]
#else // DISTRIBUTION
#define FS_URL_APPLE_VERIFY_RECEIPT [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]
#endif // (DEBUG || RELEASE)
```

Comment: I found your addPayment method is inside your  productsRequest didReceiveResponse method, just like my last try which makes the app crash during the waiting for the response from the App Store. Why you don't have a crash issue during the waiting? And, I cannot count on the case that sandbox takes more time than the real appstore.

Comment: My wait time is less than 1 minute, do you experience the same waiting time? Maybe the delegate method is the issue. Perhaps the class that handles the request is deallocated while there is still a delegate pointed towards it. When Apple's fires the delegate it could cause a crash in those situations. A way to test this, is to transform your class into a Singleton and use it as such in your app. The Singleton will not be released until your app closes down, so will always be ready to capture delegate response.

Comment: My waiting time is around 5 sec. Waiting is not a problem to me. It's crash issue. I think I've already used the Singleton, but it still jumped back to main menu of the iphone after waiting for more than 3 sec. And it doesn't crash when debugging in Xcode (using the physical device, click RUN in Xcode), it crashed when testing in iPhone (not connected with the Xcode).

Comment: Update: If I simply removed my startPayment method, leaving my requestProduct there, I will get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS after getting response from AppStore, if I run the app in Xcode. The position is in MyApp>Thread 1>0 objc_release. The code is like, ldr r1,[r1,#16], which I cannot understand. Anyone help? Thank you very much!